# jQuery Autocomplete order of results

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the [jQuery-autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) to get suggestions for completion of the input string using an AJAX call to a server. Also, the server takes care of returning the results in the order I would want them to appear but autocomplete shows them in a different order.

How can I configure jQuery autocomplete to not reorder the output ? I don't require any kind of processing on the client's end as the data has already been ranked/sorted as required.

Comment: what you mean by "auto complete shows them in a different order" ?

Comment: I mean that the order of strings displayed in the dropdown is different from that returned by the server, (which is a string of "\n" separated sequence of characters, as given in the documentation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be simpler than I thought. I decided to read the code of the plugin and modify it by commenting out the code that sorts my output.

That is when I found a variable 'sortResults:true' in defaults. So, all I needed was to set that variable to false. I didn't find this in the documentation though.

`$('#search').autocomplete ( { url: "index.php", sortResults: false } )`

Now the output is in the exact order that I require.

I got the idea of reading the code to find/solve the problem from here : [jQuery "Autocomplete" plugin is messing up the order of my data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594297/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-is-messing-up-the-order-of-my-data)
(That isn't the same plugin)

Thanks. :)

Comment: Will surely do that, after 48 hours.

Comment: That's more like it, so much easier to display the pre-processed result from the server than doing it client side. +1

Comment: Are you sure you are using the [jQuery UI AutoComplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/autocomplete/) ? I've browsed the GitHub source and API documentation and  
1. the url parameter does not exist 
2. sortResults never appears anywhere in the source (the 1.8 version) ...

Comment: `sortResults` doesn't exist as an option and this doesn't seem to work.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 20):

Simply sorting the server results before sending it to autocomplete should do it.

So before you `echo json_encode($return_arr);` use the `sort()` function on `$return_arr`

**You can also try something like this:**

The logic is to build up an array of matches that start with the term, and then concatenate that with matches that contain the term but don't start with it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var source = ['Adam', 'Benjamin', 'Matt', 'Michael', 'Sam', 'Tim'];
    $("input").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term)
                , startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
                , startsWith = $.grep(source, function(value) {
                    return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                })
                , containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i")
                , contains = $.grep(source, function (value) {
                    return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 &&
                        containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
                });

            response(startsWith.concat(contains));
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zkVrs/

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/8302996/973155

Comment: `the server takes care of returning the results in the order I would want them to appear but autocomplete shows them in a different order.`  It sounds like the OP is already doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8302996/277923
I read this from the above link, but I am unable to fathom how can I use this to do 'no sorting' at all. I would like jQuery-autocomplete to show the result in the order returned by the ajax call.

Comment: I have shared the relevant code in the next answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10950584/277923

Comment: Farhan, if you didn't write the above code, it's etiquette to share its source. Andrew Whitaker posted this last year in the link  rajatkhanduja mentioned above.

Comment: this is perfect! Sorting items that start with the term before alphabetical sort is a huge usability improvement when autocompleting large sets. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857001/autocomplete-search-for-a-specific-key-word answer please

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no sortResults options in current build of jQuery Autocomplete plugin, I had to search another solution to this problem and found out the only reason the plugin is sorting result is that server response is being normalized everytime it's not a pure array with objects {label: ..., value: ...}.

Considering PHP as a language of your use, **json_encode(array_values($your_array));** should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @sKopheK! Just to clarify, provide this to the source function's response parameter: `[ {label: "suggestion", value: "suggestion"}, ]` -- not this: `["suggestion",]`